# Show $-y'' + q(t)y = \lambda y$ has a solution $\phi_1(t,\lambda)$ on $- \leq t \leq \pi$ with initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I trying to do this exercise: [image]

Following the hint, I consider the integral equation $$\phi(t,\lambda) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t)}{\sqrt{\lambda}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \int_0^{t} \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(t-s))q(s)\phi(s,\lambda)ds$$

For the first term of the successive approximation I say: $\phi_0(t,\lambda) = 0$, because $0$ is our initial data. Then $$\phi_1(t,\lambda) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}t)}{\sqrt{\lambda}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\lambda}} \underbrace{\int_0^{t} \sin(\sqrt{\lambda}(t-s)q(s)\cdot 0)ds}_{0}$$

But then $\phi_2(t,\lambda)$ is complicated to compute because the integral is complicated. Is there a nice way to compute the successive aproximation of this integral equation? Am I doing something wrong?